# SQL Like for non ASCII glyph

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

As you know TSQL has the CHAR() that returns character.  This is very useful when the character is a non-ASCII glyph such as

ie.  `SELECT CHAR(191)` gives **¿**

Question:  Is there a way to use this CHAR() function in a LIKE '%CHAR(191)%' query?   The reason I ask this is not every symbol is visible and I want to search them up in order to replace them such as

ex: Replace "µ" with "micro"

```
 REPLACE(Description,'µ','micro') WHERE Description like '%µ%'
```

but I wish to do it similar to this:

```
 REPLACE(Description,CHAR(181),'micro') WHERE Description like '%CHAR(181)%'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, you just need to concatenate the string instead of leaving it all in quotes:

```
WHERE Description like '%' + char(181) + '%'
```

Comment: lol, such a simple solution.  I am embarrassed that I did not think about this.